# Optimizing Entity Framework (Multiple queries per model in gridview)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am working on an application in WinForms. My data is stored in an MSSQL server (Azure). Part of my application includes some basic billing features. One model I have is Invoices, but I have run into quite the performance issue. My first question really is, who is to blame? My poorly optimized code or the underlying entity framework. The main issue lays in when I am displaying a list of invoices in a DataGridView. For each invoice that I list, I need to make multiple calls to the DBContext. Is that unresonable? I need to make multiple calls for this reason; one to get the list of invoices to display (Based on the FK CustomerID), and then for each Invoice model I call some methods which calculate things like SubTotal, TaxTotal, Etc. Those functions are below.

```
    public decimal SubTotal()
    {

        decimal subtotal = 0;
        List<Billing_InvoiceItems> LineItems = db.Billing_InvoiceItems.Where(a => a.InvoiceID == this.id).AsNoTracking().ToList(); 
        {
        foreach (var LineItem in LineItems)
            subtotal += (LineItem.Cost * LineItem.Quantity);
        }

        return subtotal;
    }

    public decimal TaxTotal()
    {

        decimal taxtotal = 0;
        List<Billing_InvoiceItems> LineItems = db.Billing_InvoiceItems.Where(a => a.InvoiceID == this.id).AsNoTracking().ToList();
        foreach (var LineItem in LineItems)
        {
            if (LineItem.Taxable)
            {
                taxtotal += LineItem.Cost * (decimal) LineItem.TaxPercentage; 
            }
        }

        return taxtotal;
    }

    public decimal Total()
    {

        return (this.SubTotal() + this.TaxTotal());
    }

    public decimal TotalDue()
    {
        return (this.Total() - this.TotalPaid());
    }

    public decimal TotalPaid()
    {

        List<Billing_PaymentToInvoice> paymentsToInvoice = db.Billing_PaymentToInvoice.Where(a => a.InvoiceID == this.id).ToList();
        decimal totalpaid = 0;
        foreach (var Payment in paymentsToInvoice)
        {
            totalpaid += (decimal)Payment.AmountApplied;
        }

        return totalpaid;
    }
```

Am I being unreasonable by needing to make multiple SQL "Queries" per Invoice that I list? Or is there a way I can optimize these functions? I have tried one approach as to cache the invoice items (allowing me to calculate the totals for display to the user) However, this required me to then have a function which i seemingly called often to keep the cache up to date.

EDIT: You'll see .AsNoTracking() in there on the LineItems query, this was an attempt at optimizing it from some searching online.

Comment: Cache should do it. There are different cache models you could do, even avoiding to recalculate Sums entirely. (when you add the new item you can just add cost to your cached total value).

btw There is SQL SUM aggregate function, however I don't know if its faster than your calculations.

Comment: Yeah, that is really really inefficient. You can fetch all your invoices and their line items in 1 db call: `var invoices = db.AsNoTracking().Invoice.Include(i => i.LineItems).Where(i => i.??? == xxx).ToList();` Now use that in memory model to do your calculations and filtering. Things like caching and AsNoTracking() will have far less impact than minimizing your DB calls.

Comment: @SteveGreene Line Items are stored in a separate table, does that make a difference?

Comment: Not in a properly configured EF model. You should have a navigation collection of line items under the invoice. See [here](http://aspalliance.com/2067_Code_First_Development_Using_the_Entity_Framework.2) for example.

Comment: @SteveGreene this is a Data-First project, models generated by VS Scaffolding.

Comment: Then it should have the collection added automatically so long as you made a FK relationship in the database.